# Geometric meaning of localization with an example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, solution-verification, localization

My task is to understand the following example:

Let $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy).$ Let $p=(x-1)$ be the ideal of $R$. Show that $(x-1)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ and deduce that the localization at this maximal ideal $R_{p} \cong$ $\mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}$. What does this geometrically mean?

My attempt:

$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy)/(x-1) \cong \mathbb{R}[y]/(y) \cong \mathbb{R}$ which is a field. So the ideal $(x-1)$ is maximal hence prime.
$R_{p}=R_{R\setminus p}=\left\{\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy): g(x,y) \text{ is not divisible by the polynomial $x-1$}\right\}$. So we are looking at rational functions in $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy)$ which are well defined in a neighborhood of the point $(1,0)$ and also at the point $(1,0)$. Is my argument valid?

Comment: Politely, this is a bit of a mess - you don't need to prove $(x-1)$ is an ideal, it's defined to be the ideal generated by $x-1$; you claim that the quotient of $\Bbb R[x,y]/(xy)$ by $(x-1)$ is a field and therefore $(x-1)$ is maximal, but this is the smallest part of that attempt paragraph and you don't even seem to notice that you've proven the claim! I think you would be served well by simplifying and being really clear about what you're doing and why you're doing it.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry for the mess. I have edited my question. Can you take a look at it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is the ring of polynomial functions defined on the algebraic variety $V$ given by equation

$$xy = 0$$

The natural morphism $\mathbb{R}[x,y]\rightarrow R$ representing the restriction of functions. This variety is equal to the union of two irreducible varieties: one given by $x= 0$ (the vertical axis), and the other by $y=0$ (horizontal axis). So, $V$ is just a cross (pair of intersecting lines).

The ideal $(x-1)$ of $R$ is just the (maximal) ideal $(x-1,xy)$ of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ modulo $(xy)$. It corresponds to the intersection of the vertical line $x-1=0$ with the cross, which is the point $(1,0)$.

In a neighborhood of the point $(1,0)$, which is on the horizontal component of the cross, $V$ coincides with the line $y=0$ (the ring of functions on that line is just the polynomial ring in one variable $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(y) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]$), and that is the geometric reason why the localization of $R$ (the cross) at the point $p$ is the same as the localization of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (the horizontal line) at the point $x=1$ (because those varieties are the same near that point).

The proof of the isomorphism $R_p \cong \mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}$ is as follows. Let $f$ be the localization morphism $f: R \rightarrow R_p$. The image of $x$ in this morphism is invertible because $x$ is not in $(x-1)$. So, from the relation $xy= 0$ (true in $R$) we get the same relation in $R_p$, where it implies $y = 0$ (because $x$ is invertible here).

This shows that $(y)\subset \ker f$, but the only non trivial ideals that contain $(y)$ are maximal ideals, and since $\ker f$ is not maximal (because the image $R_p$ is not a field), this means that $(y) = \ker f$.

By now, it should be clear that $R_p$ consists precisely of polynomials in $x$ (because $y = 0$) with the additional property that each polynomial not in $(x-1)$ is invertible. This ring is then equal to $\mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}$. This is the algebraic reason.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Just for curiosity: Can you give the explicit map of the localization morphism?@Compacto

Comment: Yes. As you said, elements in $R_p$ are just "rational functions", and every polynomial is obviously a rational function, giving the "inclusion" map $R \rightarrow R_p$. This is like "enlarging" the ring to allow for some fractions of its elements. I don't know if the term "localization map" is standard.